# custom numbers in ionic 2 range

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

The standard ionic range has a min/max number for the range of possible values.

```
<ion-range min="1" max="20" ...>
```

What I want is a custom range, for example, I want the slider to only select these values: {1, 5, 7, 20}.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried playing around with the `(ionChange)` event of the `Range` component, but I was not able to make it work properly. Instead, you can use a few buttons and a disabled range to create your own range element. Please take a look at [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dUWlqw?p=preview).

There you can add a button to increase the value, and another one to decrease it.

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-list-header>
    Your super cool value <ion-badge item-right>{{ value }}</ion-badge>
    </ion-list-header>
    <ion-item>
    <ion-range  disabled="true" step="1" min="1" max="20" [(ngModel)]="value">
      <ion-label range-left><button outline round small (click)="decrease()">-</button></ion-label>
      <ion-label range-right><button outline round small (click)="increase()">+</button></ion-label>
    </ion-range>
  </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

And then in your code, you can force the range element to take a value only between the ones you need (1, 5, 7 and 20 in this case)

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  templateUrl:"home.html"
})
export class HomePage {

  private prevValue: number;
  private value: number;

  constructor() {   
    this.value = 1;
  }

  public decrease() {
    if(this.value == 5) {
        this.value = 1;
      } else if(this.value == 7) {
        this.value = 5;
      } else if(this.value == 20) {
        this.value = 7;
      }
  }

  public increase() {
    if(this.value == 1) {
        this.value = 5;
      } else if(this.value == 5) {
        this.value = 7;
      } else if(this.value == 7) {
        this.value = 20;
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working a bit more on [sebaferreras](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915438/sebaferreras)' answer.

First add your slider with (ionChange) and set min/max so it matches the length of your custom steps [1,5,7,20] = 0-3. This can also be done dynamically by calculating the array length.

The {{customSteps}} will print your custom values

The HTML:

```
<ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
        Slider with uneven steps
    </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
<ion-content>

    <ion-badge item-right>{{customSteps}}</ion-badge>

    <ion-range 
        min="0" 
        max="3" 
        [(ngModel)]="slider" 
        (ionChange)="watchSlider()" 
        snaps="true">
    </ion-range>

</ion-content>
```

Your watcher function will convert the slider values to you custom values. Remember: The custom steps array must be of the same length as your slider to be able to match numbers dynamically.

The code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
        templateUrl:"home.html",
})
export class HomePage {
    slider: any = 1; //Holding the actual slider values
    customSteps: any; //Holding the custom values

    constructor() {
        this.watchSlider(); //initializing the slider
    }
    watchSlider(){
        //Converting slider-steps to custom values

        const steps = [1, 5, 7, 20];
        this.customSteps = steps[this.slider];
    }

}
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4YH27n?p=preview)